# Trying to automatically change dropdown values in a google sheet, if the data matches from another sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have 2 columns B & C

- B includes names
- C includes a dropdown with 2 options - IN & OUT

I have another column - G, that has a list of names and some of the names matches from the main list in column B

Is there a way to automatically change the dropdown value in column C from OUT to IN if the name matches from the list in column G?

Please refer to the sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t4OCg2rVQxV0pE1dT1xzOrzzkbyGS0KaPtiLFmHu8U8/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You need scripting then. Other you can use array formula cells C4:C to change values automatically. When you need to change value automatically then why you will use dropdown? Use formula instead.

Comment: If you wish about formula then could try `=BYROW(B4:B28,LAMBDA(x,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,G4:G10,0)),"IN","OUT")))`. See your sheet.

Comment: Thank you sir, using a formula is better approach. Your answer is really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish about formula then could try following formula. See your sheet.

```
=BYROW(B4:B28,LAMBDA(x,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,G4:G10,0)),"IN","OUT")))
```